# How to set up tamplateUrl for 'ng-view' in angularJS within Express.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I got two questions.

1.When I am using express.js and angularJS, which one will process the request uri first?

2.The folder layout in express looks like:

```
 project
    |-- bin
    |-- node-models
    |-- public
    |   |-- images
    |   |-- javascripts
    |   |-- stylesheets
    |-- views
    |-- routes
    |-- app.js
    |-- package.json
```

when I put index.html in views, and angularJS relate files in public/javascripts. How should I set up tamplateUrl for ng-view in index.html? I try relative path and absolute path. But both of them doesn't work.

Comment: Where is your index.html file ? Or your main script file where AngularJS main module is declared?

Comment: My index.html is in the folder 'views'. And all script files are in the 'public'.